# How can I build react-native components for different build types/flavors?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

On react-native, there's a feature were we can use a components file suffix to build different components according to platform, ie. `component.ios.js` and `component.android.js` will build a `component` module with specific behavior for ios and android.

Is there any way to build different components according to build variants/flavors/schemes? Say, suppose I have a `pro` and a `lite` version of my app, I'd like to do something like this:

```
| some-folder/
| -- component.pro.js
| -- component.lite.js
```

and so when I `import component from 'some-folder/component'`, the bundler could detect if I'm using a `pro` or `lite` build variant and bundle the correct javascript file, in a similar manner that it's done for the OS suffixes.

Do notice that I know that I can just check the build variant at runtime and provide the correct component correctly, but that means bundling the code for the wrong variant in the app - increasing app size needlessly.

Related, is there a way to import images conditionally according to build variant? I know I could just place them in their respective assets folders for each native platform, but I wonder if there are other methods.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

no thats not possible as React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android. extension and load the right file for each platform.

you have to write your own wrapper for each file like

component

--> component.pro.js

--> component.lite.js

--> index.js

in index.js file you have check platform or os from react native and return specific file

for example file

```
import ComponentPro from './component.pro.js';
import ComponentLite from './component.lite.js';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

export defualt Component=(props)=>{
  if (platform.os==='pro') return <ComponentPro {...props}/>;
  else if (platform.os==='lite') return <ComponentLite {...props}/>;
}
```